# How to unbind the key for a specific map?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, use-package, smartparens

I use *org*, *smartparens* and *use-package* altogether. Sometimes I need to delete a heading and its subheadings. Without *smartparens* package I use the <kbd>C-k</kbd> key and it allows me to delete the heading itself and all the nested text too.

But when I activate `smartparens-global-strict-mode` the <kbd>C-k</kbd> key binds to the `sp-kill-hybrid-sexp` function. After that calling <kbd>C-k</kbd> deletes only the first line and leaves all the nested text.

I tried to unbind it, but it didn't work.

```lisp
(use-package
  smartparens
  :custom (smartparens-global-mode t)
  (smartparens-global-strict-mode t)
  :bind (("C-c s a" . sp-beginning-of-sexp)
         ("C-c s e" . sp-end-of-sexp)
         :map smartparens-strict-mode-map
         ("C-k" . nil)))
```

Therefore, I ask you to guide me on how to unbind the key for a specific map?

Comment: You can check the function `C-k` is bound to without `smartparens` (possibly `kill-visual-line`). That should help you narrow down. I could not reproduce the behavior with `org-mode` and `C-k` in the absence of `smartparens`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965966/unset-key-binding-in-emacs/13966287#13966287